# Xamarin.Forms Help optimize load times

Tags: android, loops, optimization, xamarin.forms

I am making an application in Xamarin Forms and I have a Login when loading the application. The case is that when I put the data, I make a call to an API and it returns a series of data in a json.

Then I go through the json, checking that each data exists in my local database (sqlite), if it exists, I update it, if it does not exist, I insert it.

Once it has gone through all the json it loads the following activity, or screen ...

The problem is that it easily takes 10 to 15 seconds to move on to the next activity.

Any idea how to optimize this process? Or, should I modify the API to get less data?

CODE:

Login.xaml.cs

```
namespace WorkersApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string user = "";
        public string password = "";

        private async void btnEncript_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (userEntry.Text != null && passwordEntry.Text != null)
            {
                user = userEntry.Text;
                password = EncriptarMD5.MD5Hash(passwordEntry.Text);

                string url = "https://api.com/?f=login&u=" + user + "&pw=" + password;

                await GetDataFromApi(url);

            }
        }
        public async Task GetDataFromApi(string url)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await myClient.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //ERRORES
                    var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Errores>(content);
                    List<string> errror = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in error.error)
                    {
                        errror.Add(item.Value);
                    }
                    //Tiro error.
                    if (errror[0] != "0")
                    {
                        Preferences.Set("IdError", errror[0]);
                        Preferences.Set("Nombre", errror[1]);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Preferences.Set("IdError", errror[0]);
                        Preferences.Set("Nombre", errror[1]);
                    }

                    //HOTELES

                    var hoteles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hoteles>(content);

                    List<Model.Hoteles> lista_hoteles = await App.Database.GetHotelesAsync();
                    List<Model.Bloques> lista_bloques = await App.Database.GetBloquesAsync();

                    foreach (var item in hoteles.hoteles)
                    {
                        Model.Hoteles h = new Model.Hoteles();
                        
                        h = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Hoteles>(item.Value.ToString());
                        h.ID = item.Key.ToString();

                        var bloques = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bloques>(item.Value.ToString());
                        bool existe = false;
                        foreach (var bloque in bloques.bloques)
                        {
                            existe = false;
                            Model.Bloques b = new Model.Bloques();
                            b.ID = bloque.Key.ToString();
                            b.Nombre = bloque.Value.ToString();
                            b.IDHotel = item.Key.ToString();
                            foreach (var iLista in lista_bloques)
                            {
                                if (b.ID == iLista.ID)
                                {
                                    existe = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (existe)
                            {
                                await App.Database.UpdateBloquesAsync(b);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await App.Database.SaveBloquesAsync(b);
                            }
                        }

                        existe = false;
                        //if exists
                        foreach (var iLista in lista_hoteles)
                        {
                            if (h.ID == iLista.ID)
                            {
                                existe = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (existe)
                        {
                            await App.Database.UpdateHotelesAsync(h);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await App.Database.SaveHotelesAsync(h);
                        }

                    }

                    //SECCIONES
                    var secciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Secciones>(content);

                    List<Model.Seccion> lista_secciones = await App.Database.GetSeccionesAsync();
                    

                    foreach (var item in secciones.secciones)
                    {
                        Model.Seccion s = new Model.Seccion
                        {
                            ID = item.Key.ToString(),
                            Nombre = item.Value
                        };
                        bool existe = false;
                        //if exists
                        foreach (var iLista in lista_secciones)
                        {
                            if (s.ID == iLista.ID)
                            {
                                existe = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (existe)
                        {
                            await App.Database.UpdateSeccionAsync(s);
                        }
                        else{
                            await App.Database.SaveSeccionAsync(s);
                        }

                    }
                    string data = Preferences.Get("IdError", "");

                    if (data == "0")
                    {
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new HomePage();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", Preferences.Get("Nombre", ""), "Cerrar");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION:::: " + exc);
                await DisplayAlert("Error", exc.ToString(), "Cerrar");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
namespace WorkersApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : Shell
    {
        public IList<Seccion> Secciones { get; set; }
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(async () =>
                Secciones = await App.Database.GetSeccionesAsync()).Wait();
            foreach(var item in Secciones)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Nombre);
                switch (item.Nombre)
                {
                    case "Partes":
                        FlyPartes.IsVisible = true;
                        //Meter Partes en Parte
                        string url = "https://api.com/?f=partes.getList";
                        Task task = GetPartesFromApi(url);
                        break;
                    case "Auditorias":
                        FlyAuditorias.IsVisible = true;
                        break;
                    case "Maquinas":
                        FlyMaquinaria.IsVisible = true;
                        break;
                    case "Pisos":
                        FlyPisos.IsVisible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task GetPartesFromApi(string url)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await myClient.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Errores>(content);
                    List<string> errror = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in error.error)
                    {
                        errror.Add(item.Value);
                    }

                    if (errror[0] != "0")
                    {
                        Preferences.Set("IdError", errror[0]);
                        Preferences.Set("Nombre", errror[1]);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Preferences.Set("IdError", errror[0]);
                        Preferences.Set("Nombre", errror[1]);
                    }

                    var partes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Objetos.Partes>(content);

                    List<Model.Partes> lista = await App.Database.GetPartesAsync();
                    foreach (var item in partes.partes)
                    {
                        Model.Partes p = new Model.Partes();
                        
                        p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Partes>(item.Value.ToString());
                        p.ID = item.Key.ToString();
                        bool existe = false;
                        //if exists
                        foreach (var iLista in lista)
                        {
                            if (p.ID == iLista.ID)
                            {
                                existe = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (existe)
                        {
                            await App.Database.UpdatePartesAsync(p);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await App.Database.SavePartesAsync(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION:::: " + exc);
                await DisplayAlert("Error", exc.ToString(), "Cerrar");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Partes.xaml.cs

```
namespace WorkersApp.Pageviews
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Partes : ContentPage
    {
        public IList<Model.Partes> Partess { get; set; }
        public Partes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Task.Run(async () =>
                Partess = await App.Database.GetPartesAsync()).Wait();
            int contador = 0;
            foreach (var item in Partess)
            {
                Color c = Color.Black;
                if (contador % 2 == 0)
                {
                    c = Color.FromRgb(64, 64, 64);
                }
                var partesBoxClick = new BoxView()
                {
                    WidthRequest = 900,
                    HeightRequest = 120,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    BackgroundColor = c,
                    ClassId = item.ID

                };
                var partesBoxClick_tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                partesBoxClick_tap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
                {
                    //OPEN PARTE
                    GetDatosParteFromApi("https://api.com/?f=partes.get&id= " + partesBoxClick.ClassId, partesBoxClick.ClassId);
                };
                partesBoxClick.GestureRecognizers.Add(partesBoxClick_tap);
                PartesListaView.Children.Add(partesBoxClick, 0, contador);
                Color color = Color.Red;

                Console.WriteLine("COLOR::::  " + item.Operacion);
                switch (item.Operacion)
                {
                    case "nuevo":
                        color = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case "asignado":
                        color = Color.GreenYellow;
                        break;
                    case "en progreso":
                        color = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case "anulado":
                        color = Color.Gray;
                        break;
                    case "en ejecucion":
                        color = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
                        break;
                    case "cerrado":
                        color = Color.Green;
                        break;
                    case "terceros":
                        color = Color.Firebrick;
                        break;
                }

                PartesListaView.Children.Add(new BoxView() { BackgroundColor = color, WidthRequest = 5, HeightRequest = 120, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start }, 0, contador);
                PartesListaView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.Titulo, FontSize=16, FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Bold, Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start }, 0, contador);
                PartesListaView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.Departamento, Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 18), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End }, 0, contador);
                PartesListaView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.Hotel, Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End }, 0, contador);
                PartesListaView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.Fecha, Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 18), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End }, 0, contador);
                PartesListaView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.Prioridad, Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End }, 0, contador);
                contador++;
            }
        }

        public async Task GetDatosParteFromApi(string url, string id)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await myClient.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //GET ERROR
                    var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Errores>(content);
                    List<string> errror = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in error.error)
                    {
                        errror.Add(item.Value);
                    }

                    if (errror[0] != "0")
                    {
                        Preferences.Set("IdError", errror[0]);
                        Preferences.Set("Nombre", errror[1]);
                        return;
                    }
                    //GET DATOS
                    List<string> ids = new List<string>();
                    List<string> idsh = new List<string>();
                    var Datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parte>(content);
                    string parte_datos = "";
                    string parte_fotos = "";
                    string parte_historico = "";
                    foreach (var item in Datos.parte)
                    {
                        if (item.Key.ToString() == "datos")
                        {
                            List<Model.Parte> datosParte = await App.Database.GetDatosParteAsync();
                            parte_datos = item.Value.ToString();
                            Model.Parte parte = new Model.Parte();
                            parte = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Parte>(parte_datos);
                            parte.ID_Parte = id;
                            bool existe = false;
                            foreach (var iLista in datosParte)
                            {
                                if (parte.ID_Parte == iLista.ID_Parte)
                                {
                                    existe = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (existe)
                            {
                                await App.Database.UpdateDatosParteAsync(parte);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await App.Database.SaveDatosParteAsync(parte);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.Key.ToString() == "fotos")
                        {
                            parte_fotos = item.Value.ToString();
                            List<Model.Fotos> fotos = await App.Database.GetFotosAsync();
                            List<Model.Fotos> FotoList = new List<Model.Fotos>();
                            //foto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Fotos>(parte_fotos);
                            FotoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Fotos>>(parte_fotos);

                            foreach(var fotoI in FotoList)
                            {
                                Model.Fotos foto = new Model.Fotos();
                                foto = fotoI;
                                foto.ID_Parte = id;
                                bool existe = false;
                                ids.Add(foto.ID_Foto);
                                foreach (var iLista in fotos)
                                {
                                    if (foto.ID_Foto == iLista.ID_Foto)
                                    {
                                        existe = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (existe)
                                {
                                    await App.Database.UpdateFotoAsync(foto);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    await App.Database.SaveFotoAsync(foto);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else if (item.Key.ToString() == "historico")
                        {
                            parte_historico = item.Value.ToString();
                            List<Model.Historico> historicos = await App.Database.GetHistoricoAsync();
                            List<Model.Historico> HistoricoList = new List<Model.Historico>();
                            HistoricoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Historico>>(parte_historico);

                            foreach (var historicoI in HistoricoList)
                            {
                                Model.Historico historico = new Model.Historico();
                                historico = historicoI;
                                historico.idHistorico = id + historico.fechaEvento;
                                bool existe = false;
                                idsh.Add(historico.idHistorico);
                                foreach (var iLista in historicos)
                                {
                                    if (historico.idHistorico == iLista.idHistorico)
                                    {
                                        existe = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (existe)
                                {
                                    await App.Database.UpdateHistoricoAsync(historico);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    await App.Database.SaveHistoricoAsync(historico);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    string data = Preferences.Get("IdError", "");

                    if (data == "0")
                    {
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DatosParte(id, ids, idsh));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", Preferences.Get("Nombre", ""), "Cerrar");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION:::: " + exc);
                await DisplayAlert("Error", exc.ToString(), "Cerrar");
            }

        }

        private void Filter_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new FiltroPartes());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:::::

After cleaning the API, now i get fewer Tickes to check if update or save indo local sqlite.

But I just notice I still need to check the whole BBDD to login.

The API now check tickets from last 30 days from curdate and with

```
operation_state <> "Closed"
```

I think I'm login (1 call to API to check if user is good)
Then in the HomePage im getting all the tickets (1 call to API to get tickets)
AND THEN. When I click in the Tickets Menu, it loads into the listview. (So another 15 seconds).

I believe i need to remove the API call in HomePage. and add it when I click in Ticket Menu.

Will check in some time. Or tomorrow.

EDIT:

So i checked and i was right, I changed the app to get all the tickets when I tap the Tickets menu.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: in order to optimize you need to identify which specific parts are slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cristian, it's normal in mobile app development. According to the amount of data we are getting it takes time to load.

Though as you have mentioned that you are calling service and inserting data if not exist and update if exist, so this data are dynamic and getting changed every time when you call? If not than instead of updating or calling service again, use the data from local database.

If not than You can use monkey cache, that will help you to improve your app performance. But use it only in case of static data.

Another thing instead of getting all data at once from service, try to get only the data that is required and will come in your use, this will also improve your app's performance. And also decrease the amount of internet data it uses.

Refer this for more details: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/techniques-for-improving-performance-in-a-xamarin-forms-application-b439f2f04156

Also you can remove the images from app and use FontAwesome icons for that.

Hope this will help you in some or other way!

Comment: It's a Ticket Resolution App, so only the recent/not closed tickets are important in API data retrival...
So I believe it's not important to get closed tickets?

Comment: Yes, correct. You have to identify such un-necessary data and remove it.

Comment: WIll check API and choose answer later. Thanks for being my little rubber duck today!

Comment: Well, lazy loading of data is one of the best ways to optimize app performance and make the look and feel of your app better. You can always use existing XF components to do so but there are some packages you can find on NuGet that will make your user experience ever slightly better

Comment: How does Lazy loading data works? I think it would be interested to learn.

Comment: Also, @divyesh_08! I modified the API and the BBDD, so closed tickets doesn't get called and Internet Data wen't down a lot. But now I have "other" problem i didn't see. Posting it on a new EDIT. Thanks.